# How to manually insert ornamental braces like the one in the quran package?

Tags: arabic, arabluatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[voc]{arabluatex}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I am using the `arabluatex` package. How do I insert the ornamental braces (image below) *manually*?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arabluatex` provides a simple way to do this, like so:

```latex
\arb{((1))}
```

Answer (score 1):

These braces are Unicode characters, i.e., `﴾`, `﴿`.

```
U+FD3E: ORNATE LEFT PARENTHESIS
U+FD3F: ORNATE RIGHT PARENTHESIS
```

You can print them with `fontspec` and appropriate font. You can define your own argument taking command. Here, I have purposely added blue color to the Arabic font, so the font-selection mechanism becomes apparent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newfontfamily\arabfnt[Color=blue]{FreeSerif}
\NewDocumentCommand{ \arabbraces }{ m }{{\arabfnt﴾}#1{\arabfnt﴿}}

\begin{document}
{%
  \arabfnt
  ﴾12345﴿%
}

{\arabfnt﴾}12345{\arabfnt﴿}

\arabbraces{12345}
\end{document}
```

[image]